# Null values using JavaScript .click() in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, dom-events

I have a web application in that I have button click event, which triggers a search. I am using JavaScript to also trigger this search when the user presses the enter key on the keyboard

In most browsers it is working fine but in Internet Explorer it always showing null values. Why would this be occurring?

```
document.getElementById('btnsearch').click()

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkEnter(e) {

        var characterCode

        if (e && e.which) {
            e = e
            characterCode = e.which
        }
        else {
            e = event
            characterCode = e.keyCode
        }

        if (characterCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById('btnsearch').click();
                                           
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

This is what I am using for button click event.

Comment: Which version of IE? If it's IE7 then maybe you are experiencing this http://remysharp.com/2007/02/10/ie-7-breaks-getelementbyid/

Comment: IE has a different event model from everybody else (i.e. every other browser).  Therefore, there is no "click" for your button.  If you want cross-browser support, you are **STRONGLY** encouraged to adopt a JavaScript library -- my personal suggestion is the Dojo Toolkit since you seem to be working with UI elements here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give like this

```
 document.getElementById('<%=btnsearch.ClientID %>').click()
```

Sure it will work.

Comment: how can you assumed this from his code? If it's working in other browsers, but no IE, then it would suggest his selector is correct (except for in IE)

Comment: I am using IE, and I had assigned like this. Its working fine. I had no problem.

Comment: but how do you know his code is the same as yours? the Id of the button may well be btnsearch, which means his selector will work.

Comment: Hi i have post my code in my Question , what i did to get this please check it  once.